# communication with modem using pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, modem, pyserial

I did not find a reasonable good example of how to talk to a serial modem using pyserial. I have created a code snippet that should do the following, given an instantiated pyserial object `ser`:

- Send an AT command to the modem
- Return the modem answer as quickly as possible
- Return e.g. None in the case of a timeout
- Handle the communication between the script and the modem most reasonable, robust and easy.

Here is the snippet:

```
def send(cmd, timeout=2):

  # flush all output data
  ser.flushOutput()

  # initialize the timer for timeout
  t0 = time.time()
  dt = 0

  # send the command to the serial port
  ser.write(cmd+'\r')

  # wait until answer within the alotted time
  while ser.inWaiting()==0 and time.time()-t0<timeout:
    pass

  n = ser.inWaiting()
  if n>0:
    return ser.read(n)
  else:
    return None
```

My question: Is this good, robust code, or can pieces be changed/simplified? I especially do not like the `read(n)` method, I would expect pyserial to offer a piece of code that just returns the whole buffer content. Also, do I / should I flush the output at the begin, to avoid having some crap in the output buffer before?

Thanks
  Alex

Comment: Be careful of the line endings, are you sure `'\r'` is the correct line ending? Normally it's either plain newline (`'\n'`) or carriage-return and newline (`'\r\n'`).

Comment: @Joachim: This is a good point I cannot answer. It should be considered as part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Create the Serial object with the param `timeout=2` for read timeout.

Mi recipe is:

```
def send(data):
    try:
        ser.write(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print "Couldn't send data to serial port: %s" % str(e)
    else:
        try:
            data = ser.read(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Couldn't read data from serial port: %s" % str(e)
        else:
            if data:  # If data = None, timeout occurr
                n = ser.inWaiting()
                if n > 0: data += ser.read(n)
                return data
```

I think that this is a good form of manage the communications with the serial port.